# How to change the type "text/plain" in non .txt files

Tags: wine, mime-type

I have Ubuntu 18.04

I have a program called "transcribe!" (software to reproduce and modify audio) that can open .xsc files.

When I make the association of the file type .xsc to Transcribe (installed inside wine), also the .txt is associating to Transcribe.

I look in propierties of the .xsc file and it saids that the type is text/plain (the same than .txt documents).

How can I change that?

Thank you so much!

Solved:  https://rlog.rgtti.com/2010/11/22/integrating-a-new-application-in-gnome/

Comment: Dear Joan, solutions should not be posted as a part of the question here on [ubuntu.se]. Consider posting a [real asnwer](https://askubuntu.com/help/self-answer) using the form below. However, a good answer should contain more than a link, see [answer]. Just sharing the link would be acceptable in a comment but this is not the preferred solution. @karel Thanks for notifying me, close vote retracted.

Comment: @Joan I saved your last post so you can copy it from [here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/QrFbGNHm4b/).